# Is it possible to display responsive Boostrap carousel in all breakpoints?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I want to display 10 slides in a row in huge screen(lg and md) and based on the breakpoint size,carousel has to display the  slides(In mobile view 1 slide and in tablet view 3 or 4 slides based on the screen size).Is it possible to design a responsive bootstrap carousel in all breakpoints?

Comment: what code have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Carousel doc:](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)

You can just create and hide stuff depending on the screen using `xs-hidden` class to hide anything on a small screen.

```
<div id="carousel-top" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="hidden carousel-indicators" style="display:none">
  <li data-target="#carousel-top" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li class="" data-target="#carousel-top" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li class="" data-target="#carousel-top" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

  <div class="item active">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="...">
</div>

<div class="item  hide-on-mobile">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="...">
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="...">
</div>

<div class="item keep-me-out-of-small-screen">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="...">
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="...">
</div>


</div>

<!-- Controls -->
<a class=" left carousel-control" href="#carousel-top" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class=" right carousel-control" href="#carousel-top" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

JQuery:

```
if ($(window).width() < 960) {
     $('#carousel-top .keep-me-out-of-small-screen').removeClass('item').addClass('hide');
}
```